# Remove div not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove appended div. I have the code to append a div on click; the **#add** button appends a div. But I'm unable to remove it using the remove button. I'm confused at how to remove it.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(function(){
           $('#item').append('<div class="form-group"><div class ="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><input type="text" name="document"  class="form-control" /></div> <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ><input type="file" name="image[]"  class="form-control"  /></div><div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ><button class="del">Remove</button></div></div>');

        });

        $('#item').on("click",".del",function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();

        });


        });
        </script>   


    <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="pass1" class="control-label col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ><span style="cursor:pointer" id="add">Add More</span></label>

                        </div>

                        <div id="item">
                        <div class="form-group"  >

                          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >

                            <input type="text" name="document"  class="form-control"  />

                          </div>  
                          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" >

                            <input type="file" name="image[]"  class="form-control"  />

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
 $('#item').on("click",".del",function(){
        $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();

     });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q9xbqck0/4/)**